# How to use semaphores

Tags: semaphore

We have two processes A and B that will run concurrently:
ProcessA:
Statement A1;
Statement A2;

Process B
Statement B1;
Statement B2;

By use of semaphore(s) how can I state that A1 is executed before B2 and B1 is executed before  A2.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the concept of the semaphores. The exact problem is to proove that A1 comes before B2, where B1 executes before A2.

Comment: process A sets a flag saying it is in progress.
Process B checks flag if it is allowed to go.
While it is not allowed, keep checking.
Once A is done, set flag to completed.
Process B sees it is done, sets to flag to in progress for itself, and it does its own execution.

Not sure what the problem is? Ah...misread when I commented. Anyways, my point stands, simply use some flags to show the state of things and some rules around those flags.